# How do I make Pyqt5 listWidget to print item of different colors?

Tags: python, colors, pyqt5

I wanted the Listwidget to add an item in the color red only in the message when the exception occurs. However, the moment the `setStyleSheet` is changed to `("color: red")`, all the text that comes later will also appear as red.

My goal is that only the line where the exception is printed, stays in the color red. How can I do this?

````
    try:
        self.listWidget.addItem("IP Connected: %s" %self.HOST)
        print("conected: ", tnConectado)
    except:
        self.listWidget.addItem("No is possible connect's in this IP")
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("font:bold; color: red")
        print("desconnected: ", tnConectado)```
````

Comment: Setting a stylesheet only works on widgets, and results in setting that stylesheet for *any part* of that widget, and, possibly, all its children that respect the stylesheet rules, so you should not use a generic stylesheet for complex widgets like item views in any case, and you should use [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) instead. Use `item = QListWidgetItem("It is not possible to connect to this IP")` `item.setBackground(QColor("red"))` `font = self.listWidget.font()` `font.setBold(True)` `item.setFont(font)` `self.listWidget.addItem(item)`

Comment: Also note that exceptions should be more specific. While a basic `except:` is fine for many situations, you cannot always assume the reason. From your code (which is *not* a [mre], by the way), it's unclear what kind of exception could happen, but a better implementation would be to use `except SomeExceptionYouWantToIgnore:` and *finally* use `except Exception as e:` `print(type(e))` for all other unhandled exceptions.